# Clojure, Map one function to two parameters, one parameter is fixed , other is taken from a list

Tags: dictionary, clojure

I have a function which takes two parameters.

Now i wish to :

```
(map fn x [y1 y2 y3])
```

I need result of `fn` applied on `x y1 , x y2 , x y3`

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this:

First, simply repeat `x` as needed.

```
(map fn (repeat x) [y1 y2 y3])
```

`repeat` will return a lazy sequence of xs.

The other way is to use `partial` function which is a function that is applied the part of argument already bind to the original function.

```
(map (partial fn x) [y1 y2 y3])
```

`(partial fn x)` will return a function which `x` is already applied to the original `fn`. So the result will be `((fn x y1) (fn x y2) (fn x y3))`.

Answer (score 4):

This is what partial is for.

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/partial

For your specific situation:

```
(map (partial fn x) [y1 y2 y3])
```

Answer (score 4):

`(map #(f x %) [y1 y2 y3])`

**#()** is a reader macro for (fn [args] (...))

Comment: +1 for making an anonymous function instead of partial - partial is more general than what this problem needs